# Laravel multiple models (DB tables) identical - an efficient way of programming

Tags: laravel

I am a beginner with Laravel and I have a project with multiple tables with the same fields (e.g. id, name).

I have about 10 tables with this structure (e.g. country, town, type of users,....)

I read it is correct to have for each table a separate Model and Controller.

Is this correct? Is there any efficient way to programme like maybe make a single model and controller and extend them maybe?

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it the exact same structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's correct to have a separate table for each model and controller.

You could have everything in one table and override the methods on the Eloquent model to pull everything from the same table.
Each of your models would need to have the `$table` property set to the same table.

But if you did so, you would need to add another column to the core table to identify the type of model for each row. So the JSON representation of each of your rows would look something like:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Town 1',
    type: 'town'
}
```

Then in the model you would need to override the `newQuery()` method to add a where to scope the query to the correct `type` value.

But this would all be effort wasted when you come to add more properties or relationships to your data.
For example a `town` may belong to a `country` so you'd want to include a `country_id` column on your `towns` table to key the relationship. At which point the tables for `town` and `country` are no longer the same.

Best practice is to have a table (created by a migration), model, and controller for each data entity in your application.

Answer (score 2):

it depends on the meaning of those tables.

Laravel use the MVC design pattern, it means each concept is represented by a model to persist the data, a controller to manipulate it, and a view to show it.

In Laravel you should think by model and not by table.

In your case if you want to group your tables in one because they have exactly the same fields then you can, and it will be one model. and then create a model and a controller for it.

i advice to separate the concerns, it's always better. then if on of those table need an update, than you don't have to cross everything.

You can ask more deep for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, even if you find a way to pull it off eventually it's going to come back to bite you, But if you are trying to avoid the repetition of business logic related to the database then you should look into the repository code pattern. A good case study is [L5 Repository](https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository). Though I don't accept it in its entirety because it is very opinionated about the way you should implement it, it will however give you a sense of how you can reduce repeating a few business logic and or only repeat what is absolutely necessary.